# Whats wrong with this protocol declaration?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am doing this as learning and I have been told that NSString return type type is not right.

Is it that the type should be `(NSString*)`not`(NSString)`

```
@protocol MyExampleProtocol <NSObject>

@required
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *resgisteration;
-(NSString) getModelAndRegistration();
@optional
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *engine;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *chasis;
-(NSString) getEngineAndChasis();
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to return a pointer to the NSString object since NSString is not a primitive type. Therefore you need to use

```
- (NSString *) getEngineAndChasis;
```

Also, drop the parentheses, these are not used in Objective-C

Comment: I do not think even my tutor picked it that was my java talking :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it that the type should be (NSString*)not(NSString)

Yes, the return type should be `NSString*`. In Objective-C, every thing is a reference except the primitive data types like int, float etc., Also member functions don't have a ending `()`, as in C++.

Comment: He also needs to drop the parentheses at the end of his method declaration.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice it. Edited.

Comment: Accepting other one since he beat you by a minute by thanks so much and upvoting yours.